# How do I get the session option for KDE in the login screen? (installed kde-full)

Tags: installation, kubuntu, kde, lightdm, login-screen

I've installed the package `kde-full` in Ubuntu 12.10. As I know I should be able to switch to KDE on the login screen, after it is installed. However, I only see two options:

- Ubuntu 3D
- Ubuntu 2D

What should I do to log in to a KDE session?

Comment: What package exactly did you install? `kubuntu-desktop` might be needed for the session files for LightDM to switch.

Comment: I've installed like: apt-get install kde-full

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

After that you should get the KDE option at login.

Comment: Okay, I had to reinstall the package, it works now. :)